# Complex Fundamental Theorem of Calculus Integration Question

Tags: calculus, integration

Use the Fundamental Theorem of Calculus to show, for $\lvert a\rvert>r>0,$ that
$$ \int_{\gamma(0,r)}\frac{dz}{z-a}=0.$$
By integrating $(R+z)/(z(R-z))$ around $\gamma(0,r)$ show, for $0\le r<R$ that 
$$ \int_{0}^{2\pi}\frac{d\theta}{R^2-2Rr\cos\theta+r^2}=\frac{2\pi}{R^2-r^2}.$$

I've managed to prove the first part of the question but am very stuck on how to tackle that the integral is $\frac{2\pi}{ R^2 - r^2}$.

Any help or advice would be much appreciated.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Are you familiar with partial fraction decomposition?

Comment: decomposing the LHS of the equation?

Comment: Yeah, in particular decomposing $(R+z)/(z(R-z))$ so that you can integrate it, as suggested by the problem.

Comment: Does that not decompose to 1/z + 2/R-z which integrates to 2pi*i, due to Cauchy's Integral Thm and the part above?

Comment: That is correct. Now parametrize $z$ and plug it into the integral. You should get something that's not exactly what you want, but is related somehow.

Comment: let z = re^i*theta?. I've plugged it in but transforming this into the form I want is where I am stuck atm.

Answer (score 1):

So you've shown (in the comments) that
$$ \int\limits_{\gamma(0,r)}{\frac{R+z}{z(R-z)}\text{ d}z} = 2\pi i.$$
Parametrizing $z = re^{i\theta}$, we see that the integral becomes
$$\int\limits_{0}^{2\pi}{\frac{R+re^{i\theta}}{re^{i\theta}(R-re^{i\theta})}ire^{i\theta}\text{ d}\theta} = i\int\limits_{0}^{2\pi}{\frac{R+r\cos\theta+ir\sin\theta}{R-r\cos\theta-ir\sin\theta}\text{ d}\theta} = i\int\limits_{0}^{2\pi}{\frac{R^2-r^2 +2iRr\sin\theta}{R^2-2Rr\cos\theta+r^2}\text{ d}\theta} $$
(verify the last equality by multiplying by conjugates). Do you see how to proceed from here?

Comment: So take the real part of the integral? thank you so much for your help! It's greatly appreciated!

Comment: More specifically, the imaginary part of the integral will actually be zero (why?). So you're just left with the real part.

Comment: does it integrate to [i* log((R-r)^2)? ]

Comment: It doesn't; it should integrate to zero. (Consider parity)

Comment: It's an odd function about theta = pi? therefore integrates to 0

Comment: Yep! You could also argue that it's odd around $0$ and change the limits of integration to $\int\limits_{-\pi}^{\pi}$, which may be a simpler argument to understand (but really it's the same argument).

Comment: Yep, I get it now. Thanks so much again for your help!

Comment: No problem! If you found my answer helpful, you can upvote and accept the answer. Accepting the answer will give both of us reputation points. :)